# Moving ECS containerDefinition command to locals - Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I am working with Terraform to deploy an ECS Service with some containers. Code is so long so I was trying to move all logic to locals.tf.

Right now, my code at container definition is like this:

```
module "prometheus" {
  source = "../aws-modules/ecs-service"

  [... more code ...]

  volumes               = local.prometheus_volumes
  cpu                   = var.prometheus_cpu
  memory                = var.prometheus_memory
  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
[
  {
    "image": "${var.prometheus_container_image}",
    "name": "${lower(local.prometheus_name)}",
    "networkMode": "${var.prometheus_network_mode}",
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": ${var.prometheus_container_port},
        "hostPort": ${var.prometheus_container_port},
        "protocol": "tcp"
      }
    ],
    "command": [
      "/bin/prometheus",
      "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
      "--web.enable-lifecycle",
      "--storage.tsdb.path=/prom_data"
    ],
    [... more code ...]
  }
]
DEFINITION
```

This is working as expected, but I am trying to leave it like this:

```
module "prometheus" {
  source = "../aws-modules/ecs-service"

  [... more code ...]

  volumes               = local.prometheus_volumes
  cpu                   = var.prometheus_cpu
  memory                = var.prometheus_memory
  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
[
  {
    "image": "${var.prometheus_container_image}",
    "name": "${lower(local.prometheus_name)}",
    "networkMode": "${var.prometheus_network_mode}",
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": ${var.prometheus_container_port},
        "hostPort": ${var.prometheus_container_port},
        "protocol": "tcp"
      }
    ],
    "command": "${local.prometheus_container_command}",
     [... more code ...]
  }
]
DEFINITION
```

And declaring this on locals.tf:

```
prometheus_container_command = <<DEFINITION
    [
          "/bin/prometheus",
          "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
          "--web.enable-lifecycle",
          "--storage.tsdb.path=/prom_data"
     ]
DEFINITION
```

I have done similar things on containerDefinitions, but never with an array, so I am facing this error *(if I remove the newline, then the errors point to "/" from "/bin/prometheus")*

[image: error]

> !    Error: ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error decoding JSON: invalid character '\n' in string literal
> on ../aws-modules/ecs-service/main.tf line 147, in resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecs_task_definition":
> 147:   container_definitions    = var.container_definitions

*if I delete the "[":*

> !    Error: ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error decoding JSON: invalid character 't' after array element
> on ../aws-modules/ecs-service/main.tf line 147, in resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecs_task_definition":
> 147:   container_definitions    = var.container_definitions

and I don't know what more I can try (I have tried deleting "[", without "DEFINITION", etc...)

Some of you have tried to declare an array and use it on ECS containerDefinition?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of quotes in

```
"command": "${local.prometheus_container_command}"
```

will lead to the `command` being:

```
"command": "["cpmd1","cmd2", "cmd3"]"
```

Please try :

```
 "command": ${local.prometheus_container_command}
```

or

```
 "command": ${jsonencode(local.prometheus_container_command})
```